# Overflow-x: auto, without hiding content

Tags: html, css

I've just made this section of images, where you're supposed to scroll horizontal to see the different images, and by the looks of the following screenshot, this is visually almost the result I wanted, with a few style changes to come

[Section without overflow applied: the result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAiBt.jpg)

However, when I apply overflow-x: auto, in order to allow horizontal scrolling, the section cuts off the images on the right hand side:

[Section with overflow applied: NOT the result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2rP2.jpg)

How can I make the section horizontal scrollable but without cutting the images off on the right?

It is basically a flexboxed section with three images so far:

```
<section class="projectSlideshow">
    <img 1>
    <img 2>
    <img 3>
</section>

.projectSlideshow {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
height: 75vh;
margin-bottom: 2.25rem;
}
```

Comment: looks like you have set padding or margin on the right side.

Comment: i tried making something like that and u should add overflow auto to the projectslideshow it should work

Comment: Something like this? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bxh3kc0r/1/)

Comment: @OMiShah, I do have about 9rem margin on each side. Just want to override those margins like it does on the first screenshot, which overflow-x does not do, when I apply it. It just cuts off the content.

Comment: Yeah something like that, @Jayr

Comment: If that result you wanted its okay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, sometimes, the solution you're looking for is so simple that you don't even think of it.

I solved it by putting the `<section class="projectSlideshow></section>` outside of my `<div class="content"></div>` (which contains the text above and below the slideshow, which is using padding to push in the text (the section was inside of it at first)), making them siblings to each other, instead of the section a child of the div.

Putting the `<section>` outside of `<div>` makes it possible for the slideshow to go from border to border (100% width). Then just **adding the same margin-left to the first image as well as the same margin-right to the last image as the padding of the text** gives the exact result I wanted.

[A quick video of the result](https://youtu.be/fbxdv13xxgE).